# Ubuntu issue with "man"

Tags: ubuntu, man, kde-neon

When I try to run `man -k .`, I only get a list of commands starting with `pvck`. So when I run `man ls` for example, I get a blank page that asks me to select h for help or q to quit. The same thing happens when I run `man sudo` and `man apt`. Alternatively, if I run `man --help` or `ls --help` then I will get the correct output there.

I am using KDE Neon (Ubuntu 18.04). Let me know if you need any other information. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it is a KDE problem? Did you try in a TTY just to check that out? What says `type man` (should be /usr/bin/man)

Comment: Mine does show /usr/bin/man when I run `type man`. Yes, in a TTY I see the same thing for the man pages.

Comment: So likely unrelated to KDE, Neon and Konsole, I suggest removing these tags. Your distro and release may be more pertinent.

Comment: Got it, I've update the original post. It's on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've found the answer on https://forum.pine64.org/showthread.php?tid=6787&highlight=manpages. It looks like we need to install something called apparmor to fix this. The code I ran was `sudo apt install apparmor-utils &&
sudo aa-disable /usr/bin/man`.